# Adding a Calendar object to a ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform, calendar, android-calendar

I wish to add a Calendar object to the ParseObject I have created but its throwing an exception whenever I try to add it:

```
ParseObject route = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_ROUTES);
route.put(ParseConstants.KEY_ROUTE_PROPOSED_TIME, mProposedDateTime);


  09-05 12:57:55.735  16977-16977/com.khackett.runmate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.khackett.runmate, PID: 16977
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class java.util.GregorianCalendar
```

I am getting the Calendar object from the previous intent as follows:

`mProposedDateTime = (Calendar) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("proposedTime");`

What is the recommended way to add a Calendar object to Parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Parse you need a **Date** object, for accomplish this you must call `getTime()` like this:
`route.put(ParseConstants.KEY_ROUTE_PROPOSED_TIME, mProposedDateTime.getTime());`